# Adobe Animate How do I slow an Animation Down if its too fast?

Tags: animation, effects, adobe-animate

I have an animation I created in Adobe Animate I was wondering is there a fast way to slow the animation down if it plays too fast. I have my animation going about every 15 frames unless I wanna speed it up in the middle somewhere but the whole overall animation is playing back too fast.

Comment: You can either change the fps to something lower, or you can select all frames in the animation and stretch them (so that every frame stays for 2 frames for example)

Comment: how do I "stretch them"

Comment: Select the frames in the timeline and drag & drop the right edge to stretch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an Answer sort of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OrNev6nwnA this video seems to explain A process of going about slowing the animation down. I might re-ask this if I can later because I am trying to slow the overall animation down and not just a symbol in the animation.